# About io test in linux by cpp program

Tags: c++, linux, io, virtual-machine

Hi I write a simple code to read large(10GB) binary file to memory and measure the running time in a kvm's guest `virtual machine`.

Large file is created by `fallocate -l 10GB test.bin`

Four results

case 1. First time or after `[shutdown->boot]`: 17s

case 2. Second time: 4s

case 3. After clear the cache buffer[by running `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` or `rm file and recreate file`]: 6s

case 4. After reboot: 13s

I think case 1,3,4 should get the same results, because the buffer cache is cleared, but why they get different results now???

here is the code snippet

```
int test()
{
    int ret = 0;
    streampos size;
    char* buffer;

    //define file pointer pointed to a large_file
    ifstream large_file("test.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);

    if(large_file.is_open()){

        size = large_file.tellg();//get the size of large_file
        buffer = new char[size];//allocate memory
        large_file.seekg(0, ios::beg);//set get position to the begin of the file

        start = wtime();
        large_file.read(buffer, size);
        large_file.close();
        end = wtime();
        printf("File size = %ldGB Time = %.5f\n", size/1024/1024/1024, end-start);

        delete buffer;
        return ret;
    }
    else printf("failed to open the file\n");

    ret = 1;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Since this is tagged as C++ you should post your code too

Comment: It's questionable how meaningful those numbers are. Depending on your environment, you may be sharing resources with any number of things that aren't under your control...

Comment: @KerrekSB my confusion is case 1,3,4 should get the same results, because the buffer cache is cleared. They are nearly the same conditions

Comment: What filesystem are you writing to? And what is the host system and filesystem, and did you clear the cache in the host as well?

Comment: You could also get inconsistent results if your program goes into swap, either in the VM or host.